# Localize Listpicker Items in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, listpicker

I am trying to use the listpicker control in my windows phone 7 app,  I have the xaml set up correctly, but I want to use strings from my resource file instead of the literals (for Yards and Meters) that I currently have set up:

```
    <toolkit:ListPicker Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.unit_of_length_title, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
        <sys:String>Yards</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Meters</sys:String>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

I have tried the following:

```
    <toolkit:ListPicker Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.unit_of_length_title, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
        <sys:String>{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.measure_yards, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}</sys:String>
        <sys:String>{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.measure_meters, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}</sys:String>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

but it is not binding to the resource strings.  I know that I could create a Data Template, and Bind that way,  but I am looking for a simpler solution, any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at why "it is not binding to the resource strings"?

Comment: I googled this pretty thoroughly, and searched extensively on SO.  It seems like no one is really localizing their win phone apps. It just seems like there should be a simple solution to this though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.unit_of_length_title, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.measure_yards, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.measure_meters, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```